# Design : Exposing common functionality to two different classes

Tags: c++, oop

There is a common module `Logging`. There are two other modules `Foo` and `Bar` who are going to use the functionality provided by `Logging`. One way is to have a global Logging object and passing this object to `Foo` and `Bar` during construction who will maintain a reference to this `Logging` object.

```
Logging Logger;
Foo foo(Logger);
Bar bar(Logger);
```

Somewhere in `Bar`:

```
Bar::SomeFunc()
{
    this->Logger.func();
}
```

This would work but I would have to create and maintain the global `Logger` object. Also if tomorrow some another common module like `Reporting` comes up, I would have to pass that to `Foo` and `Bar` as well.

Another way is to have a Base class `Common` having Logger as a static object. Now `Foo` and `Bar` would inherit from `Common` and can access the functionality exposed by `Logger` and since it is static even though `Foo` and `Bar` would have there own `common`, there would be a single underlying `Logger`.

This works but does not look like a use case of inheritance.
Is there a better design to handle this.

Comment: I think loggers are one of those horizontally-crossing things that are the exception to the rule when it comes to global variables. Create a single static global and reference that everywhere, assuming you want one instantiation with a fixed config.

Comment: @Joe I don't see how they make an exception. I just had a case where loggers being globals created a problem. The only difference is that the tempatation to make them globals is bigger, but the problems that come with globals are the same

Comment: Fair enough. There’s always exceptions to the exceptions. I think the OP’s idea of a common base that references the static logger is fine, too, which gives the opportunity to override as needed in a derived class.

Comment: @joe. Moreover logger is an analogy. There could be something more complex and could be multiple of them.

Answer (score 0):

My personal advice, for the case of logging, is to use a singleton Logger class, and access it through static methods.

If you need different loggers, you can extend this `Logger` class to have some form of dependency injection there, but keep the clients simple and not over engineer them.

The 'design pattern' idiomatic answer to this question is to use Dependency Injection.

`Foo` & `Bar` would have a constructor, that takes an ILogger* pointer, and store the pointer internally. You would log through that pointer. The users of Foo & Bar would pass the pointer to the relevant Logger implmentation.

I dislike this solution for such a simple use case, and in my opinion this is not good design. I'm only adding it for completeness sake.